# Android - "A spinner does not support item click events. Calling this method will raise an exception."

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have a program with a screen that has about 50 buttons, it looks rather ugly.  Each button has an async download in it, it is just copied from button to button with the URL and file name saved as changed.  I want to be able to change from using buttons to using one spinner, hopefully with just one async download task and the spinner operating as the way to select the download URL and the filename to save as.  Is this even possible?  After reading some documentation about it I got confused.  Thanks for the help.

Update:

With the suggested code from below I created this:

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity{


public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private Button startBtn;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

Spinner spDownloadFrom;
private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerArrayAdapter;
String url[]= {"www.abc.com/download/a.txt",
    "www.abc.com/download/a.txt",
    "www.abc.com/download/a.txt",
    "www.abc.com/download/a.txt",
    "www.abc.com/download/a.txt",
    "www.abc.com/download/a.txt",
    "www.abc.com/download/a.txt"
    };
String links[]= {"Server 1",
    "Server 2",
    "Server 3",
    "Server 4",
    "Server 5",
    "Server 6",
    "Server 7",
    };
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SpinnerActivity.this);
mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please be patient, file downloading...");
mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);


spDownloadFrom=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);

spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, links);
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spDownloadFrom.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

spDownloadFrom.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerListener(spDownloadFrom));
}
public class SpinnerListener implements OnItemSelectedListener
{
Spinner sp;
public SpinnerListener(View v)
{
    sp=(Spinner)findViewById(v.getId());
}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    //Call to download class
        new DownloadFile().equals(url[arg2].toString());


}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> { //put your download code

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    mProgressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
    try {

        URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        connection.connect();
        int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
        int tickSize = 2 * fileLength / 100;
        int nextProgress = tickSize;

        Log.d(

        "ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + fileLength);

        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/Android/Data/"
                + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/files";
        File file = new File(path);
        file.mkdirs();
        File outputFile = new File(file, "test1.pdf");

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024 * 1024];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            if (total >= nextProgress) {
                nextProgress = (int) ((total / tickSize + 1) * tickSize);
                this.publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
            }
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
}
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
     Log.d("Downloading",progress[0]);

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Android/Data/" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
            + "/files/test1.pdf");
    Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(SpinnerActivity .this,
                "No Application Available to View PDF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
 }
```

Is this correct for what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Example extends Activity{

Spinner spDownloadFrom;
private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerArrayAdapter;
String url[]= {"www.abc.com/download/a.txt",
        "www.abc.com/download/a.txt",
        "www.abc.com/download/a.txt",
        "www.abc.com/download/a.txt",
        "www.abc.com/download/a.txt",
        "www.abc.com/download/a.txt",
        "www.abc.com/download/a.txt"
        };
String links[]= {"Server 1",
        "Server 2",
        "Server 3",
        "Server 4",
        "Server 5",
        "Server 6",
        "Server 7",
        };
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    spDownloadFrom=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.addQuotation_spinnerProduct);

    spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, links);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spDownloadFrom.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    spDownloadFrom.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerListener(spDownloadFrom));
}
public class SpinnerListener implements OnItemSelectedListener
{
    Spinner sp;
    public SpinnerListener(View v)
    {
        sp=(Spinner)findViewById(v.getId());
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        //Call to download class
            new DownloadFile().equals(url[arg2].toString());


    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> { //put your download code

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {



        return null;

    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
         Log.d("Downloading",progress[0]);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
    }
}
 }
```

It is a sample class to meet your requirement. I did not run it so sorry if there is some mistake, but basic idea is here.

Comment: This looks amazing!  I'm gonna test it out now!

Answer (score 1):

Very possible.  Set your data into an array and create the spinner.  While true that a spinner doesn't support click events, it does do selection, so you would have some code like this after you create the spinner:

```
yourSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Nothing to do here
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int pos, long id) {
        // Your code to get the URL and filename here
    }
});
```

You could have it fire immediately upon selection by putting all the code necessary in the `onItemSelected`, or just set some variables there and then have a button in your layout (outside of the spinner) to take the variables you set and kick off the online activities.  The second option lets the user change their mind without starting unwanted online activity.

Hope this helps.